# Adding an action button to android notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-actionbar, alert

I want to add an action button to reminder notification so, whenever user clicks on such notification it takes the user to a layout file..

I know how add action buttons in general but how can I add an action button on notification in this code ..

need help .. thanks in advance..

**Code is Here ..**

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alert);
            mPlayer.start();
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            CharSequence from = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
            CharSequence message = intent.getStringExtra("Description");
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
            notification = new Notification(R.drawable.alert, "Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras().get("NotifyCount").toString()), notification);
            Toast.makeText(context, "New Notification Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: That means, you need button in notification bar?

Comment: yes i need to add a button in notification

Comment: Jiya, I think you need to create custom button there

Comment: Have you got something ot not @Sparrow?

Comment: Jiya, are you got my message or not??

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html visit this link

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alert);
        mPlayer.start();
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        CharSequence from = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
        CharSequence message = intent.getStringExtra("Description");
        PendingIntent contentIntent =      PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.alert, "Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.addAction(R.mipmap.yes, "Acion_Name", contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras().get("NotifyCount").toString()), notification);
       Toast.makeText(context, "New Notification Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

So you just need to add .addAction 
This line of code where where you will call your Pending Intent:

```
notification.addAction(R.mipmap.yes, "Acion_Name", contentIntent);
```